# Set action bar title corresponding to ActionBar tab title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, title

When the active tab in my app is changed and an other tab gets the active tab, I would like the ActionBar title to be set to a certain text. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `Activity` implement the `ActionBar.TabListener` interface:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
        setTitle(tab.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){}

    @Override
    onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){}

}
```

And voila! It works! There you go :)

Comment: The thing is that I'm using icons and not a text, what must I do then? :)

Comment: Well then you have to find some way to convert the icon title into text and pass it to the tab :)